# Observable helpers in JS Views

Tags: observable, jsviews

I'm trying to have an element update based on an observable fed to a helper.

Observable:

```
var siteGlobal = {
    page: null,
    parent: null
};
```

Helper

```
$.views.helpers({
    navState: function(id) {
        var cssClass = "nav_item";
        if (Number(id) === siteGlobal.parent) {
            cssClass += " current_page_parent";
        } else if (Number(id) === siteGlobal.page) {
            cssClass += " current_page_item";
        }
        return cssClass;
    }
});

$.views.helpers.navState.depends = [siteGlobal, "parent"];
$.views.helpers.navState.depends = [siteGlobal, "page"];
```

Element

```
<li data-link="class{:~navState(id)}" >...</li>
```

So the idea is that when the observable changes, the helper responds, comparing the value supplied from the linked element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work.

You need

```
$.views.helpers.navState.depends = [siteGlobal, "parent", "page"];
```

Now if `id` is `3`, and you call

```
$.observable(siteGlobal).setProperty("page", 3);
```

then class will get set to `"nav_item current_page_item"`

Call

```
$.observable(siteGlobal).setProperty("parent", 3);
```

and it will get set to `"nav_item current_page_parent"`

See [www.jsviews.com/#computed@depends](http://www.jsviews.com/#computed@depends).